kube-prometheus-stack only scrapes data from the node it is running on
I'm running an EKS cluster and have installed the kube-prometheus-stack using Helm.
but I only see data from the node which kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus running on.
Also when I see Get "https://XXXX:10250/metrics": context deadline exceeded on
http://<prometheus-panel>/targets for all the nodes except one of them (which is the one kube-prometheus-stack running on it)
also clsuter security group is for both inbound and outbound:
All traffic
All
All
–

I am using latest version of both helm chart and EKS

I ended up allowing traffic through the EKS security group for each node in the cluster, which also resolved the 'metrics not available' issue in Lens.
